# how to find all usages of enum in a method with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

For a specific method I want to know which specific values of a particular enum is being used (by reflection).
For example:

```
public class Example1
{
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        None,
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    }

    public int Method1()
    {
        MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.One;
        Console.WriteLine("myEnum " + myEnum);
        return (int)myEnum;
    }
}
```

This method uses the value MyEnum.One of the enum MyEnum.

Comment: Without a full static analysis you will be not able to find the usages. `MyEnum.One` for example will be compiled to a simple `ldc.i4.1` opcode.

Comment: @thehennyy i know that.. So how do I use full static analysis to find those usages?

Comment: The question says "using reflection".  That isn't possible.

Comment: You could create something like an abstract syntax tree from the il code to find all places where integers are treated as enum-values. Decompilation-libs like dnlib/dnspy may already provide such kind of data-structues and information.